# Is it required to compare social access token with Social Email ID in Social Auth?

Tags: django, access-token, google-signin, social-authentication

When using Social Auth, Email ID is auto validate with Social(Google, FB) account.

But I want to develop api for social auth.Mobile developer are using GOOGLE/FB SDK and provide me email.

Issue:

Is Social access token require, so comparing it with email ID received and then process the data if social access token received from social auth matched with Email?

Answer (score 0):

After much RnD, the Concept became clear. Actually it is not an issue, but my false understanding.

An access token is saved on 3rd party and is not required to log in, but needed to get a refresh token.